# How do you pull all data from a joined table when a related record contains a given value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

I have created the following query:

```
SELECT wvwcs1.*, wvwcs2.* FROM wvwcs1

inner join wvwcs2 on wvwcs1.id = wvwcs2.wvwcs1_id
inner join wvwcs2 w2 on wvwcs1.id = wvwcs2.wvwcs1_id AND wvwcs2.value LIKE '%ee%'
```

My tables are created like so:

```
CREATE TABLE `wvwcs1` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `form_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='      ';

CREATE TABLE `wvwcs2` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `wvwcs1_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=32 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The data, as an example just using two records:

```
mysql> select * from wvwcs1;
+----+---------+
| id | form_id |
+----+---------+
|  1 |      23 |
|  2 |      24 |
+----+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)



mysql> select * from wvwcs2;
+----+-----------+-------+
| id | wvwcs1_id | value |
+----+-----------+-------+
|  1 |         1 | aa    |
|  2 |         1 | bb    |
|  3 |         1 | cc    |
|  4 |         2 | aa    |
|  5 |         2 | cc    |
|  6 |         2 | dd    |
|  7 |         2 | ee    |
+----+-----------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What I need to do, is to select all the records from `wvwcs2` where ONE of the records in `wvwcs2` is a given value. So, assume that we want to select records where `wvwcs2.value` = `dd`. In this case, we would get returned:

```
+----+-----------+-------+
| id | wvwcs1_id | value |
+----+-----------+-------+
|  4 |         2 | aa    |
|  5 |         2 | cc    |
|  6 |         2 | dd    |
|  7 |         2 | ee    |
+----+-----------+-------+
```

When I run this query currently, it gives me all records. I thought I would need to do an inner join on the same table, but I must be off. I am stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.*, C.form_id
FROM wvwcs2 A JOIN 
(SELECT DISTINCT wvwcs1_id FROM wvwcs2 WHERE LOWER(`value`) LIKE '%dd%') B
ON A.wvwcs1_id=B.wvwcs1_id
LEFT JOIN wvwcs1 C 
ON A.wvwcs1_id=C.id;
```

See [Demo on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/80fb38/2).

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is what you want here:

```
SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM wvwcs1 A JOIN wvwcs2 B ON A.id = B.wvwcs1_id
WHERE A.id IN
(SELECT wvwcs1_id FROM wvwcs2 WHERE value like '%ee%');
```

See [Demo on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/80fb38/3) (based on cdaigas initial work)

After the first comment the easiest solution seems to be the following (no need to join anything here at all):

```
SELECT * FROM wvwcs2 WHERE wvwcs1_id IN 
   (SELECT wvwcs1_id FROM wvwcs2 WHERE value like '%ee%');
```

Comment: i needed to select all records from wvwcs2 of the same wvwcs1 id when one of those had a value equal to `ee`

Comment: I edited my answer so my 2nd solution should be just what you need without any joins at all.